# Between spring mvc and spring boot which should I learn for web development

Tags: java, spring

I'm beginner to spring and i want to develop web application. Which should I study between spring mvc and spring boot?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/index.html

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "both". :-)

More specifically: you learn web development by writing web services. Spring Boot makes it easy to get a Spring MVC service up and running quickly. The concepts you learn will map to non-Boot, even non-Spring, projects.

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot uses spring-mvc under the hood (if you use the web dependency).

So better learn spring boot which will get you up and running quickly.

You will learn spring-mvc specific feature eventually if you keep going...

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot is a easier way to use Spring MVC, because you don't need to install dependency manager, container, configs are simpler, etc.

But I got your question and I suggest you to start with Spring Boot, because you will make things work easily, so you won't get frustrated in the beginning. If you feel the need to use only Spring mvc, try it in the future.

Go to https://start.spring.io/ to generate your first project.